# jQuery callback and prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype-programming

I create the following class :

```
APP.core.View = function () {
    var self = this;

    $.ajax ( { url: 'test.html' } ).done ( self.build );

    return self;
};


APP.core.View.prototype.build = function ( source ) {
    var self = this;

    // this refers to the AJAX callback.

    return self;
};
```

As you can see in the `build` method, the reference to `this` (the one belonging to APP.core.View) has been lost. How can I get it back ? I know I could pass a ref to `this` in the AJAX callback like this :

```
$.ajax ( { url: 'test.html' } ).done ( function ( source ) {
    self.build ( source, self );
} );
```

But I don't really like it as I feel like a method should never loose the ref to its object.

Any idea/suggestion ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to create a cross platform solution

```
APP.core.View = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.html'
    }).done($.proxy(this.build, this));
    return this;
};
```

For modern browsers, you can use [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
APP.core.View = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.html'
    }).done(this.build.bind(this));
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found another answer in the jQuery AJAX doc. The jQuery.ajax function provides a `context` argument which lets you specifies the callbacks context. Example :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

Source : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/